# How to route traffic to subdomain.example.com where example.com is a local server and subdomain is a different device

Tags: dns, routing

I may need to do some more planning, but here's the setup.

I have a standard wireless router port-forwarding to my server from a static IP on my cable modem.

Anything that hits *.example.com or www.example.com goes to that server.

I'm not running a local DNS server.  I may need to, not sure.

My goal is to have subdomain.example.com forward to a different ip address on my network.  Since both www.example.com and subdomain.example.com are traveling over port 80, the router sends all of those requests to the server.

If there was a way for the router (AirPort Extreme) to recognize subdomain.* and thus forward to a different IP and port, that would be fantastic, but it doesn't have that capability.

So, additional routing needs to be done at the server level, I'm assuming.

What would I need to install and configure to make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform this with an reverse proxy. Apache can handle this with the [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Here is an configuration example :

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName subdomain.domain.com
  ProxyPass / http://yourrealhost.com/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://yourrealhost.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

You can even redirect to another port just by setting `http://yourrealhost.com:3000/`in the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse.